# Linear Application that is open in a TVS

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $T: E \to F$ be a linear map between topological vector spaces $E$, $F$. If for each nonempty open set $G$, the interior of $T(G)$ is non-empty, then, $T$ is open.

Proof:
$$\mathrm{Int}(T(G))= \bigcup_{U \subset T(G), U\in\tau_F} \mathcal{U}\neq \emptyset $$

Then, exist $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathcal{U} \subset T(G)$...

How should I proceed? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Norbert, my proof is correct?

Comment: Where did you use the vector space structure?